# GridWorld Mbug actor

Tags: java, gridworld

For class I am supposed to extend the bug actor to make a bug that makes an M on the grid. This is what I have so far but the bug does not turn in the direction specified. Instead it makes a square shape. Any help on what I am doing wrong?

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug; 
import info.gridworld.grid.Location; 

public class MBug extends Bug{

private int lineLength; 
private int steps; 
private int line;  

public MBug(int length) 
{ 
    setDirection(Location.NORTH); 
    steps = 0; 
    line = 1; 
    lineLength = length; 
} 
public void act(){  
    if (line <= 4 && steps < lineLength){ 
        if (canMove()){  
            move(); 
            steps++; 
        } 
    }else if (line == 2){ 
        setDirection(Location.SOUTHEAST); 
        steps = 0; 
        line++; 
    }else if (line == 3){ 
        setDirection(Location.NORTHEAST); 
        steps = 0; 
        line++;
    }else if (line == 4){
        setDirection(Location.SOUTH); 
        steps = 0; 
        line++; 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ta da!

[image: MBug]

Here's the code. Please tell me if you don't understand anything.

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug; 
import info.gridworld.grid.Location; 

public class MBug extends Bug{

    private int lineLength; 
    private int steps;
    /* strokeNum is basically a code to tell the bug which stroke it is on.
     * In this case, an 'M' has four strokes:
     * up, diagonal down, diagonal up, and then down.
     * This method can be used to create any letter,
     * but round strokes (C's, R's, etc.) take so many individual strokes that it's almost impossible.
     */
    private int strokeNum;

    public MBug(int length){
        lineLength=length;
        steps = 0;
        strokeNum=0;
    } 
    public void act(){  
        if(strokeNum==0){
            setDirection(Location.NORTH);
        }else if(strokeNum==1){
            setDirection(Location.SOUTHEAST);
            //This is to shorten the length of this stroke.
            steps++;
        }else if(strokeNum==2){
            setDirection(Location.NORTHEAST);
            //This is to shorten the length of this stroke.
            steps++;
        }else if(strokeNum==3){
            setDirection(Location.SOUTH);   
        }
        if(canMove() && strokeNum<4){
            move();
            steps++;
            if(steps>=lineLength){
                steps=0;
                strokeNum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```